# What is the setup.py file in github repository used for?

Tags: setup.py

How can I run the code in  [this repository](https://github.com/jxgu1016/Gabor_CNN_PyTorch) without following their steps, I want to run the `main.py` file, from the [Demo](https://github.com/jxgu1016/Gabor_CNN_PyTorch/tree/master/demo), directly.

What are the `setup.py` and `install.sh` files used for?

Answer (score 2):

`setup.py` is the canonical name for the installer of a Python package. For example, when you run `pip install x`, `pip` runs the `setup.py` of the package you installed. In this case, `install.sh` is just a shortcut for running `setup.py`.

There's no way to use a package without installing it, since it won't have what it needs to operate properly.